# filesharing app/plugin downloading only locally not existing files

Tags: p2p

I wonder if any p2p filesharing app exists (or a plugin) which can be configured to scan all locally existing files and identify them (hash, or PUID for audio, etc) so when the user searches and chooses many files at once it would download only non-existing files.

I have been googling a while but havent found anything in this direction.

Anybody got some links about research and development ?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I have never heard of a framework offering all those functionalities. Most often, people build their applications on top of existing P2P frameworks.

P.S.: I have been around P2P systems for a couple of years now.